# Show an image inside table with ng-if and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ng-if

I would like to ask you a question.
My wish is to create a table composed by 4 columns and show on table-data (3rd and 4th column of each row) an image of green circle when a variable (blocco1 or blocco2) is true and an image of red circle when the same variable is false.

This is my code

```
                        <tr ng-repeat="data in elencoTransazioni">
                            <td class="i9fontPre text-center" header-class="'i9header'">{{::data.code}}</td>
                            <td class="i9fontPre text-center" header-class="'i9header'">{{::data.desc}}</td>    
                            <td class="i9fontPre text-center" header-class="'i9header'">
                                <img ng-if="data.blocco1=='true'" src="/i9web/mock/circleGreen.png">
                                <img ng-if="data.blocco1=='false'" src="/i9web/mock/circleRed.png">
                            </td>
                            <td class="i9fontPre text-center" header-class="'i9header'">
                                <img ng-if="data.blocco2=='true'" src="/i9web/mock/circleGreen.png">
                                <img ng-if="data.blocco2=='false'" src="/i9web/mock/circleRed.png">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Can anyone could help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `ng-src`.

```html
<tr ng-repeat="data in elencoTransazioni">
  <td class="i9fontPre text-center" header-class="'i9header'">{{::data.code}}</td>
  <td class="i9fontPre text-center" header-class="'i9header'">{{::data.desc}}</td>
  <td class="i9fontPre text-center" header-class="'i9header'">
    <img ng-src="{{data.blocco2 ? '/i9web/mock/circleGreen.png'
                               :'/i9web/mock/circleRed.png'}}">
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: It doesn't work... and I don't understand why, your solution should be fine

Comment: I don't know how I can create a demo... thank you for the patience

Comment: However, the problem seems to be the true/false condition

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/oW1iEUhxMdgpRtSgPWSL?p=preview I doesn't work and I don't understand why... thanks for helping me

Comment: see updated [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tHTkITGre3JRMS6FdDCM?p=preview)

Comment: You can change `"blocco1": "true", "blocco2": "true"` to `"blocco1": true, "blocco2": true` and use `{{data.blocco1 ?  ... ` in view also.